# For every element of $\ell^2$ there is a unique $f \in H$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have to prove that for every $\alpha \in \ell^2$ there is a unique $f \in H$ such that $<f, e_j> = \alpha_j ~ \forall j \in N$ where $(e_j)$ is a Orthonormal System in a Hilbert space $H$.

I have trouble understanding what $e_j$, $f$ and $\alpha$ are.

As far as I understand, $e_j$ is an orthonormal vector and $\alpha$ is a sequence (basically also a vector) as well as $f$.

But what is $\alpha_j$? Is this a single element of $\alpha$? And how das the index $j$ of $e_j$ related to $\alpha_j$?

Comment: $\alpha_j$ is the $j$th component of $\alpha$.

Comment: Do you have a hint how to solve this problem?

Comment: To show $f$ is not unique suppose so that there is $g\in \ell_{2}$ not equal to $f$ (that is at least one component of $f$ is not equal to the same component of $g$). but still $\langle g, e_{j}\rangle=\alpha_{j}$... show that this leads to a contradiction

Comment: I don't understand why there even is an $f$ with this property

Comment: Try to show that $f=\sum_j\alpha_je_j.$ First show that the series is convergent by, for example, Bessel inequality.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You mean $\alpha = \sum_j f_j e_j$? Otherwise I don't know how to show what you wrote

Comment: What you wrote does not make sense. The symbol $\alpha$ denotes a square summable sequence of numbers. The right hand side looks like an element in $H.$ The symbol $f_j$ is undefined.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc What I wrote is the definition of a scalar product

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal system in $\mathcal{H}.$ For $\alpha\in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ consider the series
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_je_j$$ This series is convergent in $\mathcal{H}.$ Indeed we will show that the partial sums
$s_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_je_j$ satisfy the Cauchy condition. We have
$$\|s_n-s_m\|^2=\left \|\sum_{j=m+1}^n\alpha_je_j\right |^2=\sum_{j=m+1}^n|\alpha_j|^2\le \sum_{j=m+1}^\infty|\alpha_j|^2$$
Thus the Cauchy condition is satisfied. Let
$$g:=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_je_j$$ Then
$$\langle g,e_k\rangle =\lim_{n\to \infty}\langle s_n,e_k\rangle =\alpha_k$$
The element $f$ is not uniquely determined if $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is not an orthonormal basis. Indeed, in such case there exists $h\neq 0$ such that $h\perp e_j$ for any $j\in \mathbb{N}.$ Then $f:=g+h$ satisfies $$\langle f,e_j\rangle =\langle g,e_j\rangle =\alpha_j$$

If $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis. Assume $\langle f,e_j\rangle =\langle g,e_j\rangle.$ Then $\langle f-g,e_j\rangle =0$ for any $j.$ Then by the Parseval identity we get
$$\|f-g\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^\infty |\langle f-g,e_j\rangle|^2=0$$ hence $f=g.$